# How to write $210\in\mathbb Z[\sqrt{-1}]$ as a product of prime elements?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, prime-factorization

How can I write $210\in\mathbb Z[\sqrt{-1}]$ as a product of prime elements?

#### Progress

I factored $2\in\mathbb Z[i]=(1-i)(1+i)$ and $5\in\mathbb Z[i]=(2-i)(2+i)$. I cannot do it for $3$ and $7$ though.

Comment: You might start by factoring it as $2\cdot 3\cdot 5\cdot 7$; then you only need to factor each of those in $\mathbb Z[i]$.

Comment: I factored $2\in\mathbb Z[i]=(1-i)(1+i)$ and $5\in\mathbb Z[i]=(2-i)(2+i)$, I cannot do it for $3$ and $7$ though...

Comment: x @user: If, for example $7$ factors as $ab$ then $|7|^2=|a|^2|b|^2$. If neither $a$ nor $b$ are units, this very tightly restricts what $|a|^2$ and $|b|^2$ can be. And since the norm of a Gaussian integer is always the sum of two squares ...

Answer (score 2):

If $p$ is a prime with $p \equiv 3 \bmod 4$, then $p$ is a prime element in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$. This is because $x^2+1$ is irreducible mod $p$.